# Default constructed std::string c_str() value

Tags: c++, stdstring

```
std::string s1;
std::string s2;
assert(strlen(s1.c_str()) == 0);
assert(s1.c_str() == s2.c_str());
```

Does these two assert always true?

I use C++11, and I have checked the standard, the Table 63 in §21.4.2 says:

> data() a non-null pointer that is copyable and can have 0 added to it
>
> size() 0
>
> capacity() an unspecified value

I think `c_str()` is the same as `data()`. But I have some question about this defination.

1. Does "**CAN** have 0 added to it" == "**MUST and ALWAYS** have 0 added to it"?
2. Does all default constructed std::string shared a same underlay buffer?

I test on gcc, these two assert is true. I wonder does these always true for all compiler?

Comment: What is your version of GCC and compilation options? With GCC/libstdc++, the second assert should be false since C++11, where SSO is implemented. The same holds for Clang/libc++, and MSVC. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7zj5bdT9v.

Comment: @DanielLangr I am not sure what the default is, but libstdc++ has a configuration switch which decides whether a shared static object is used for empty strings and I think I remember previously seeing issues with it: `--enable-fully-dynamic-string`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/configure.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first assertion is guaranteed to succeed. `c_str()` always returns a pointer to a null-terminated string with the same string contents as held by the `std::string` object, which is an empty string for both `s1`.

The second assertion is not guaranteed to succeed. There is nothing requiring the `c_str()` returned from a `std::string` to be the same if the content is the same. Default-constructed strings do not need to share the same underlying buffer. That would be an implementation detail of a particular standard library implementation. (I think libstdc++ does something like this depending on configuration for some backwards-compatibility(?) reasons if I remember correctly, see the [`--enable-fully-dynamic-string`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/configure.html) `configure` option).

Note that prior to C++11, `data()` did *not* have the same effect as `c_str()`. `data()` was not guaranteed to give a pointer to a null-terminated string. If the string was empty, then the pointer returned by it was not allowed to be dereferenced. So replacing `c_str()` with `data()` in your examples would, prior to C++11, result in undefined behavior on the call to `strlen`.

---

The wording "*and can have 0 added to it*" is somewhat weird and I am not completely sure what it is supposed to convey, but for C++11 (draft N3337) `data()`'s return value is further specified in [[string.accessors]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/string.accessors#1) so that `data() + i == &operator[](i)` for all `i` in the range `[0,size()]` and `operator[]` is specified in [[strings.access]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/string.access#2) to return a reference to a `CharT()` (aka a null character) for `operator[](size())` without any conditions.

The strange wording has also been replaced via editorial change in 2018, see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/1879.